# ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied" Error when trying

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am staging the data in to the SQL Server from Oracle database. I put the oracle connection string in one project parameter and the password in a separate parameter. I properly connection string and password to respective project parameters. The password is marked as sensitive.  All the packages are set to "EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey" protection level and running on 64 bit runtime.

When I run the SSIS package on Visual Studio 2015, I am able to run the package. But, when I deploy the package to the SSIS server and then schedule the package to run via Tidal, I am getting this error:

```
    Package Name: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

    MessageTime: 03/04/2019 20:22:57

    Message_Source_Name: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

    Event_Name: OnError

    Message: :Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied".
```

Please advise

Comment: You likely then need to open the package Connection Managers and re-assign the needed credentials

Answer (score 2):

An environment variable can be used to hold sensitive data such as a password.  If you haven't already:

- Create the [SSIS Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-2017), SSISDB. Once SSISDB has been created and the package is executed from there, an environment can be created and the connection can be configured use a variable from this as follows.
- In SSISDB create a folder then within the folder create an environment.
- Right-click the environment and click **Properties** then go to the **Variables** page.
- On this page, create a string variable to store the password and mark it as **Sensitive**.
- Next, right click the package, or project depending on the scope of the connection manager, and press **Configure**.
- Then on the **References** page select **Add** and choose the environment you created.
- Then go to the **Parameters** page and find the Oracle connection on the **Connection Managers** tab.
- Under the **Properties** window, find the **Password** property and click the ellipsis next to it.
- Pick the "Use Environment Variable" option for **Value** and choose the variable holding the password.

I'm not familiar with tidal, but when an SSIS package that uses an environment is executed from SQL Agent the job step for the package needs to include a reference to the environment, and I'd suggest double-checking how this is handled with tidal.